# how to solve cannot read property 'mDATA' in Datatables

Tags: django, datatables

I have configured datatables with django, its working perfectly when having maximum of 6 column. When i tried to add one more column i'm getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined" 
When i inspect in chrome, get line (c.mData ===) where the error shows:
if(**c.mData===**
a){var d=w(b,"sort")||w(b,"order"),e=w(b,"filter")||w(b,"search");if(d!==null||e!==null){c.mData={_:a+".display",sort:d!==null?a+".@data-"+d:k,type:d!==null?a+".@data-"+d:k,filter:e!==null?a+".@data-"+e:k};ja(p,a)}}})}var T=p.oFeatures,e=function(){if(g.aaSorting===k){var a=p.aaSorting;j=0;for(i=a.length;j

I tried to give static data to check whether it because of dynamic render, still the same issue came.

This is my html page,

table.html

```
<div class="row mb-4">
            <div class="col-12 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="data-table data-table-feature" id="dtable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Sort key</th>
                                <th>Is delete</th>
                                <th>Prefix</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>TEST</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           {% for i in areas %}
                            <tr>

                                <td>{{ i.code }}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.description }}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.sort_key }}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.is_deleted }}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.prefix }}</td>
                                <td><a href="{% url 'edit-area-master' i.id %}">edit</a></td>
                                <td>TEST</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %} 
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I cross checked all table tags, please point out where i went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution,Now i can add any one of columns.

test.html

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
               <thead>
                 <tr>
                   <th></th>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Position</th>
                   <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for i in branches %}
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>{{ i.code }}</td>
                  <td>{{ i.description }}</td>
                  <td><a href="{% url 'edit-branch-master' i.id %}"
                     class="glyph-icon simple-icon-note"></a></td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
             </tbody>
</table>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        }],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    });

    t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
        });
    }).draw();
});
</script>
```